# Latest Qt5 does not provide EGLFS during cross-compilation

Tags: cross-compilation, qt, opengles

Some time ago I set up a Linux host to cross-compile Qt5. I used this configure command:

> ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/opt/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/opt/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/opt/qt5 -v -nomake examples -nomake tests -reduce-exports -no-pch -no-use-gold-linker

and I successfully cross-compiled Qt5.9 with EGLFS support.
Now I want update to Qt5.13.

I checked out the git repository and typed the same configure command.
Here the configure output:

```
Building on: linux-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)
Building for: devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ (arm, CPU features: neon)
Target compiler: gcc 4.8.3
Configuration: cross_compile compile_examples enable_new_dtags largefile neon shared rpath release c++11 concurrent dbus reduce_exports stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++11
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. no
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. yes
  Build parts ............................ libs
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  udev ................................... yes
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
  Zstandard support ...................... no
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... yes
  iconv .................................. yes
  ICU .................................... no
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  DTLS ................................... yes
  OCSP-stapling .......................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... no
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... yes
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. yes
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. yes
    XCB Xlib ............................. yes
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  LinuxFB ................................ yes
  VNC .................................... yes
  Mir client ............................. no
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. yes
  Socket CAN FD .......................... yes
  SerialPort Support ..................... yes
Further Image Formats:
  JasPer ................................. no
  MNG .................................... no
  TIFF ................................... yes
    Using system libtiff ................. no
  WEBP ................................... yes
    Using system libwebp ................. no
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML tracing JIT support ................ no
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. no
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Wayland Client ........................ no
Qt Wayland Compositor .................... no
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. no
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... no
  Linux Crypto API ....................... no
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
  WinRT advanced bluetooth low energy API (desktop & UWP) . no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. no
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... yes
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... no
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ yes
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. no
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
Qt Tools:
  QDoc ................................... no
Qt WebEngineCore:
  Qt WebEngine Widgets ................... yes
  Qt WebEngine Qml ....................... yes
  Embedded build ......................... yes
  Pepper Plugins ......................... no
  Printing and PDF ....................... no
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. no
  Use System Ninja ....................... no
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  WebChannel support ..................... yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ no
  Extensions ............................. no
  Building v8 snapshot supported ......... yes
  Use ALSA ............................... yes
  Use PulseAudio ......................... no
  Optional system libraries used:
    re2 .................................. no
    icu .................................. no
    libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . no
    opus ................................. no
    ffmpeg ............................... no
    libvpx ............................... no
    snappy ............................... no
    glib ................................. yes
    zlib ................................. yes
    minizip .............................. no
    libevent ............................. no
    jsoncpp .............................. no
    protobuf ............................. no
    libxml2 and libxslt .................. no
    lcms2 ................................ no
    png .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. no
    harfbuzz ............................. no
    freetype ............................. yes
    x11 .................................. no
  Required system libraries:
    fontconfig ........................... no
    dbus ................................. yes
    nss .................................. no
    khr .................................. yes
    glibc ................................ yes
  Required system libraries for qpa-xcb:
    libdrm ............................... no
    xcomposite ........................... no
    xcursor .............................. no
    xi ................................... no
    xtst ................................. no
Qt WebEngineQml:
  UI Delegates ........................... yes
  Test Support ........................... no

Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.

Either ensure that llvm-config is in your PATH environment variable, or set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
On Windows, you must set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the installation path.

WARNING: Thumb instruction set is required to build ffmpeg for QtWebEngine.

ERROR: Feature 'opengles2' was enabled, but the pre-condition '(config.win32 && !features.opengl-dynamic) || (!config.watchos && !features.opengl-desktop && libs.opengl_es2)' failed.

ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.
```

I don't understand why the OpenGL has failed this time. Perhaps I need to install some other libraries? When cross-compiling I always confused if I need to install library for my host on for the target...
As side note, it's correct the specified device? I see other people use `-device linux-rpi3-vc4-g++`.